# Duplicated class Koin org.koin and io.insert-koin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle, koin

I'm using two library that have dependencies of two different versions of Koin.

One of the library has **org.koin:koin-android:2.0.1** and the other has **io.insert-koin:koin-core-jvm:3.0.1** dependencies.

At compile time I got tons of **Duplicate class** error as below,

```
Duplicate class org.koin.android.BuildConfig found in modules jetified-koin-android-2.0.1-runtime (org.koin:koin-android:2.0.1) and jetified-koin-android-3.0.1-runtime (io.insert-koin:koin-android:3.0.1)
Duplicate class org.koin.android.ext.koin.KoinExtKt$androidContext$1 found in modules jetified-koin-android-2.0.1-runtime (org.koin:koin-android:2.0.1) and jetified-koin-android-3.0.1-runtime (io.insert-koin:koin-android:3.0.1)
Duplicate class org.koin.core.scope.Scope$injectOrNull$1 found in modules jetified-koin-core-2.0.1 (org.koin:koin-core:2.0.1) and jetified-koin-core-jvm-3.0.1 (io.insert-koin:koin-core-jvm:3.0.1)
Duplicate class org.koin.java.KoinJavaComponent$inject$1 found in modules jetified-koin-core-jvm-3.0.1 (io.insert-koin:koin-core-jvm:3.0.1) and jetified-koin-java-2.0.1 (org.koin:koin-java:2.0.1)
...
```

When I try to exclude one of them as below,

```
configurations {
    all { 
        exclude group: "io.insert-koin", module: "koin-android"
        exclude group: "io.insert-koin", module: "koin-core-jvm"
    }
}
```

I got NoClassDefFoundError at runtime on the relevant one.

When exclude **org.koin:koin-android:2.0.1**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.koin.core.KoinComponent" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/...
```

When exclude **io.insert-koin:koin-core-jvm:3.0.1**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.koin.core.component.KoinComponent" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/...
```

How can I get to use both libraries?

Comment: For those who have the same problem: https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/1130

Answer (score 4):

Koin 3.x.x has no backwards compatibility. If there is no update on the sdk which uses Koin 2.x.x version, maybe you should better find an older version for the opposite library, which uses Koin 2.x.x. But please be aware Koin version 2.2.3 also has a different path than others (Because of jcenter limitations)

Comment: Thanks for informing about version 2.2.3. I wish there was a way to switch between versions at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get to use both libraries?

You can't use both versions of Koin at the same time, but you can tell Gradle to replace one version by the other at compile time. Note that it's not the same as excluding one of the versions altogether, but really replacing one by the other.

Here's an example:

```
eachDependency { details ->
                // change org.koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel into io.insert-koin:koin-android
                if (details.requested.group == 'org.koin' && details.requested.name == 'koin-androidx-viewmodel') {
                    details.useTarget group: 'io.insert-koin', name: 'koin-android', version: details.requested.version
                }
            }
```

You can read more in Gradle's doc https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/resolution_rules.html

It is only a partial solution though (and a hacky one too), as we're still limited by the API incompatibilities between Koin 2.x and 3.x. But if what you're using from Koin 2.x is still there in Koin 3.x, that should work.

Comment: It would be a great solution if they didn't change some classpaths. eg "org.koin.core.KoinComponent" to "org.koin.core.component.KoinComponent"