# Android tests using sharedViewModel fail with java.lang.ClassCastException androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleController when upgrading Koin to 3.1.3

Tags: android, robolectric, classcastexception, android-viewmodel, koin

I'm currently using Koin version 3.1.0 and want to upgrade to the latest version (currently 3.1.4), But once I upgrade Koin to 3.1.3 are above I get the following exception when I run my tests:

```
class java.lang.Object cannot be cast to class androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleController (java.lang.Object is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleController is in unnamed module of loader org.robolectric.internal.AndroidSandbox$SdkSandboxClassLoader @5c2a3b10)
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Object cannot be cast to class androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleController (java.lang.Object is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleController is in unnamed module of loader org.robolectric.internal.AndroidSandbox$SdkSandboxClassLoader @5c2a3b10)
    at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleController.attachHandleIfNeeded(SavedStateHandleController.java:98)
    at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.onRequery(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.java:103)
    at androidx.lifecycle.StateViewModelFactory.onRequery(StateViewModelFactory.kt:37)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:160)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:139)
    at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.ViewModelResolverKt.resolveInstance(ViewModelResolver.kt:15)
    at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.scope.ScopeExtKt.getViewModel(ScopeExt.kt:67)
    at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.scope.ScopeExtKt.getViewModel(ScopeExt.kt:53)
    at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.scope.ScopeExtKt.getViewModel$default(ScopeExt.kt:45)
    at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.ext.android.FragmentExtKt.getSharedViewModel(FragmentExt.kt:59)
    at com.company.myapp.MyFragment$special$$inlined$sharedViewModel$default$2.invoke(FragmentExt.kt:61)
    at com.company.myapp.MyFragment$special$$inlined$sharedViewModel$default$2.invoke(FragmentExt.kt:39)
    at kotlin.UnsafeLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:81)
    at com.company.myapp.MyFragment.getMyViewModel(MyFragment.kt:46)
    at com.company.myapp.MyFragment.showButton(MyFragment.kt:196)
    at com.company.myapp.MySecondFragment.onViewCreated(MySecondFragment.kt:49)
    at com.company.myapp.MyFragment.onViewCreated(MyFragment.kt:56)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3019)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:551)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1840)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1758)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1701)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2849)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2784)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:262)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:478)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:246)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1391)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.RoboMonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnStart(RoboMonitoringInstrumentation.java:285)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7157)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.robolectric.shadows._Activity_$$Reflector15.performStart(Unknown Source)
    at org.robolectric.android.controller.ActivityController.lambda$start$4(ActivityController.java:129)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowPausedLooper.runPaused(ShadowPausedLooper.java:200)
    at org.robolectric.android.controller.ComponentController.invokeWhilePaused(ComponentController.java:64)
    at org.robolectric.android.controller.ActivityController.start(ActivityController.java:129)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.RoboMonitoringInstrumentation.startActivitySyncInternal(RoboMonitoringInstrumentation.java:102)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.LocalActivityInvoker.startActivity(LocalActivityInvoker.java:39)
    at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.launchInternal(ActivityScenario.java:265)
    at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.launch(ActivityScenario.java:226)
    at com.company.myapp.test.ActivityTest.launchPresentationLayer(ActivityTest.kt:31)
    at com.company.myapp.test.BaseTest.setup(BaseTest.kt:65)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.invokeMethod(RunBefores.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at com.company.myapp.test.base.StopKoinRule$apply$1.evaluate(StopKoinRule.kt:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:570)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.lambda$evaluate$0(SandboxTestRunner.java:278)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.Sandbox.lambda$runOnMainThread$0(Sandbox.java:89)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I noticed that it has something to do with the `sharedViewModel`-extension cause when I change some occurrences to `by viewModel()` the tests will succeed. However this work-around is not acceptable since I need the shared ViewModels.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade your koin version to `2.2.3` should fix it!

See this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68153833/5717791)

Comment: Downgrading is never the solution. Especially since koin v2 is [discontinued](https://insert-koin.io/docs/setup/v2/): `Koin v2.x is in end of support. Please upgrade to latest Koin v3.x`